# How Perform multiple async with better performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I would like to make multiple async calls and extract the result into a list, but I'm not sure I'm making it into the best way.

I've tried adding all the calls made with System.Net.Http.HttpClient to a list, and in the end of the function, extracting the result using a lambda. I know that it should work for a couple of calls, but increasing the number of calls, there will be a big lack of performance.

```
public async Task<string> LoopMulticurrencyGetTime (int loop)
{
    List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> responses = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
        responses.Add(ExampleClient.GetAsync("Time"));

    await Task.WhenAll(responses);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responses.Select(r =>
        r.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
public async Task<string> LoopMulticurrencyGetTime (int loop)
{

    List<Task<String>> responses = new List<Task<String>>();
    List<String> s = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
        //responses.Add(ExampleClient.GetAsync("Time"));
        responses.Add(ExampleClient.GetStringAsync("Time"));

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responses.Select(s => s.Result));
}
```

But it doesn't seems to really run asynchronous, and it doesn't look to be very smooth.

Do you have any suggestions on how improve my code's performance?

**EDIT:**

This is The ExampleController →

```
[Route("/Example")]
[ApiController]
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    ExampleService exampleService = new ExampleService();

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Time")]
    public string getTime()
    {
        try
        {
            return DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ"); ;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Loop/{loop}")]
    public async Task<String> loopTest(Int32 loop)
    {
        try
        {
            return await exampleService.LoopGetTime(loop);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Benchmark/{loop}")]
    public async Task<String> becnhmark(Int32 loop)
    {
        try
        {
            return await exampleService.Benchmark(loop);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `.Result` on a task is almost always wrong, and yes: that means you're not actually using it asynchronously here; without knowing a bit more about `ExampleClient`, it is hard to know whether cuncurrency and/or parallelism (which are quite different concepts, and you seem to be using both of them) will help. But: your `LoopMulticurrencyGetTime` code really wants some `await` instead of the `.Result`

Comment: How many calls are we talking?

Comment: Independent of what the answer to the question is, I'd suggest you restrict the `loop` value to some reasonable max value that is much smaller than Int.MaxValue.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the 'HttpFactory' as well when there are lots of calls to be made. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: Thank you for Replying to you 2 both.

@MarcGravell i will try with the await, but i'm not sure to how to do it in the correct way.

usselite The calls are quite irrilevant, i just wanna try some benchmark in that case, to understand if the LoopMulticurrencyGetTime  function is good in performance or not. i'll start look at your suggestion thank you :)

By the way, i'm thinking to make to loop to do at least 100 async calls, and then await them to finish. because i think that make them without limit, could be a really problem

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really not clear here. In general, your first method is fine. Though, like others have said, there should be some bound on the loop value.

It's also not clear what you think is wrong with the second "desired" method, other than the fact that you've omitted the `Task.WhenAll` call of the previous method. If you add that, then this form would work just fine as well.

First, you need to realize that async is not about performance; it's about scale. Async code very often will be *less* performant that sync code, if for no other reason than async incurs some overhead. This might only amount to a matter of milliseconds, but call-for-call, async code will be slower than sync on average.

What async buys you is scale. You can handle slight more requests with async than with sync, and in general, resources are better utilized. That's it.

Now in terms of why you're not find this particularly performant in general, there could multiple causes for that. First, you have not specified *how* you're running this. If you're testing inside Visual Studio, for example, you're dealing with a single-threaded web server (IIS Express), so requests are still processed serially even with async. On another setup, you may simply be exhausting available resources. Async is not free. There's still stuff happening and if there's not enough RAM or CPU, if network latency is high, etc. all those things can contribute to bad performance still.

In general, async is not a magic wand. You're still very much bound by hard constraints. Async just makes better use of available resources than sync, but it's still bounded by said resources.

Comment: Hi, really thank you for your reply.

To reply to your second "is not clear": i was asking for the best code writing.
I'm doing this stuff in java via spring, and i want to do it also in .net to see the differences and also to study this tecnology.

You've been very clear about the differences.

To do a sort of stress-benchmark function that call (on localhost) a lot of time an exposed endpoint, had you done some of different? or you had choose the way i used in the second function?

Thank you very much

Comment: In general, this type of benchmarking is useless. ASP.NET Core, in general, is fast. I don't use Spring, but given its maturity, I'd wager it's "fast" as well. What bogs any framework down is what you add to it, i.e. the various bits of middleware that are included and the actual real world code that you're running. In short, if you want to profile these two frameworks, actually build something approximating a real world task, using the appropriate middleware and such that you would actually be using. Then, use an actual load testing application.

Comment: I'm sorry if i was not clear, but the benchmark is not about the framework, but about my code's implementation. i was trying to understand which code was better and took more advantages from .net's tools like async/await.